# How to start method from fragment b in fragment a, with specyfic show

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I have a problem with starting method from fragment in another fragment.

I have 2 fragment. On with a drawer and in drawer i can choose the dialogFragment with informations. I ican open just a fragment but i want to create one fragment for all options.

So fragmentB is DialogFragment.

This is main method that i want call

```
 public void configureSettingsMenus(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case TRADING_HISTORY:

            break;
        case LEADER_BOARD:

            break;
        case SPECIAL_OFFER:

            break;
        case VIDEO_TUTORIALS:

            break;
        case FAQ:

            break;
        case CONTACT:

            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong, try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
```

And this is that class

```
    public class SettingsFragment extends DialogFragment {


    private static final int TRADING_HISTORY = 1;
    private static final int LEADER_BOARD = 2;
    private static final int SPECIAL_OFFER = 3;
    private static final int VIDEO_TUTORIALS = 4;
    private static final int FAQ = 5;
    private static final int CONTACT = 6;


    String[] data = {"HERE", "WILL", "BE", "GAME", "HISTORY"};

    public SettingsFragment() {
    }

    public static SettingsFragment newInstance(int num) {
        SettingsFragment f = new SettingsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game_history, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_games_recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new WinLostHistoryAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }

    public void configureSettingsMenus(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case TRADING_HISTORY:

                break;
            case LEADER_BOARD:

                break;
            case SPECIAL_OFFER:

                break;
            case VIDEO_TUTORIALS:

                break;
            case FAQ:

                break;
            case CONTACT:

                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong, try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }


    }

}
```

And in FragmentA i create this:

```
DialogFragment settingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance(1);

 private void configureDrawer(){
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withSliderBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
            .withActivity(getActivity())
            .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
            .withDrawerGravity(Gravity.LEFT)
            .withHeaderPadding(true)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new SectionDrawerItem().withName("Options"),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Trading History").withIcon(R.drawable.trading_history).withIdentifier(1),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Leader Board").withIcon(R.drawable.leade_board).withIdentifier(2),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Special offer").withIcon(R.drawable.special_icon).withIdentifier(3),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Video tutorials").withIcon(R.drawable.video_tutorials).withIdentifier(4),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("FAQ").withIcon(R.drawable.faq_icon).withIdentifier(5),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("CONTACT").withIcon(R.drawable.contact_icon).withIdentifier(6)
            )
            .buildForFragment();

    result.setOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            if(position == 6)
            {
                result.closeDrawer();
                settingsFragment.show(ft, DIALOG_LOST);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

and in s`etOnDrawerItemClickListener` i want to call method from fragmentB

And my question is HOW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside the `onItemClick(...)` callback:

```
if (settingsFragment != null && settingsFragment instanceof SettingsFragment) {
    ((SettingsFragment) settingsFragment).configureSettingsMenus(position);
}
```

You have to [Type Cast](http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-object-typecasting) the class because in `FragmentA` you are holding a reference to a `DialogFragment`, which is an abstraction of the `SettingsFragment` class and does not contain the method `configureSettingsMenus(...)`.

You have to cast your `DialogFragment` instance to the concrete `SettingsFragment` in order to have access to the method `configureSettingsMenus(...)`.

**-- Alternatively --**

Hold a reference to the concrete `SettingsFragment` class within `FragmentA`.

replace:

```
DialogFragment settingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance(1);
```

with:

```
SettingsFragment settingsFragment = SettingsFragment.newInstance(1);
```

Then inside the `onItemClick(...)` callback you can simply call the method directly without Type Casting:

```
settingsFragment.configureSettingsMenus(position);
```